# What is the best way to center and give a fixed width to a content inside a 100% width background?

Tags: css, centering

What is the best way to center and give a fixed width to a content inside a 100% width background? I`m not too sure if I made my point clear, so here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/xJ8Qy/

```
.something-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    background:#fff000;
}
.something {
    background:#fffddd;
    color:fff;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

<div class="something-wrapper">
    <div class="something">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip Seat eros ornare pharetra orci at eros orn are nec nec conse.
    </div>
</div>
```

this works perfectly fine, however is it correct or is there a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: You are doing it right.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest and most robust way of doing it, works in all browsers.

Comment: If you asked for an alternative solution, you might get other answers involving `table-cell` which might be useful in other contexts.

Comment: well alright then, thanks everyone :} and Marc in this case table-cell wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

A good, and very common, way to center an element is to use a fixed width and `margin: auto` as you do

```
.something {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

---

Another way is to use `text-align: center` on the parent element, but the child element needs to be `inline-block` or similar. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ8Qy/1/)

```
.something-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.something {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```